# How do i give guest access to my user through firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login a user as a guest which means he can only view whatever is there but not interact with anything. I had some problems doing this.

First of all I used anonymous login, so that is working perfectly to sign in the user.

Now I want the user to select from a list of areaUIDs to view details of only that particular area

My database looks like this,

```
Areas 
   -AreaUID1 
      -Admin 
         -Admin1UID 
              -admin_name:"" 
              -admin_area:"" 
              -admin_email:"" 
         -Admin2UID 
              -admin_name:"" 
              -admin_area:""
              -admin_email:""
              .
              .
      -Events
          -EventUid1
                -event_name:""
                -event_timings:""
         -EventUid2
                -event_name:""
                -event_timings:""
            .
            .

      -Gallery
          -ImageUid1
                -image_link:""

  -AreaUid2
       -Admin 
         -Admin1UID 
              -admin_name:"" 
              -admin_area:"" 
              -admin_email:"" 
         -Admin2UID 
              -admin_name:"" 
              -admin_area:""
              -admin_email:""
              .
              .
      -Events
          -EventUid1
                -event_name:""
                -event_timings:""
         -EventUid2
                -event_name:""
                -event_timings:""
            .
            .

      -Gallery
          -ImageUid1
                -image_link:""
```

and so on.

Now I want to show the user a list of the several admin_area located in different AreaUids. I am using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and I need help implementing the  above problem. I want the user to be able to view all the gallery images and events from a particular area that he/she chooses.

```
mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Areas");
allAreaUids = new ArrayList<>();
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            //This is where i want to populate my arraylist with all the AreaUids. How do i do it?
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        System.out.println(databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mDbRef.addValueEventListener(listener);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, allAreaUids);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_areas);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My Areas class (note the constructors and the getters and setters methods are also present

```
public class Areas {

    private Events Events;
    private GalleryPics Gallery;
    private Admin Admin;

    public Areas(){

    }


        .
        . 
        . 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing it Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the `Events` of a specific area, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference areasRef = rootRef.child("Areas");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String areaUid = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference eventsRef = rootRef.child("Areas").child(areaUid).child("Events");
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String event_name = child.child("event_name").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", event_name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            eventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
areasRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In the same way you can get all the `Gallery` of a specific area.

Comment: Ummm i get your idea here but there is no child named as "Events" inside Admin. By the way i just managed to solve it. Inside onDataChange i did this-                                                                             for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String areaUid = snapshot.getKey().toString();
                    arr.add(areaUid);

                }

Comment: Yes, there is no `Events` inside Admin. Just removed that child. Both Events and Admin are at the same level. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The part where you add the .child(areaUid) is where i was stuck.I want to fetch the areaUids and i think you assumed that i have already fetched the areaUid and just wanted to print the event names of those respective areaUid. Although that code to fetch the event names and other data is correct until and unless we dont find areaUid the code wont work :)